# The greeting screen in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS when pc wakes from sleep is white

Tags: 16.04, gnome, login-screen, screensaver

[image: This is what it looks like now]
This used be a picture with some textures, how do go about changing this screen?

Comment: Try opening **Settings > Background > Lock Screen** and picking an image.

Comment: I'm an idiot, sorry for posting this.